# 14 days and four Thai cities. How to plan it?

Tags: thailand

If you want to visit the following cities in two weeks how do you plan it? How many days in each city?

- Bangkok (including Ayuttaya)
- Pattaya
- Phuket (including Phi Phi Islands)
- Chiang Mai

I am thinking because I want to do some shopping and I don't want to carry them around maybe I stay in Bangkok as the last city. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

How do you plan to enter and leave Thailand?  By plane to and from Bangkok, I guess.  If so then Bangkok can easily be your first or last.  Pattaya would sensibly be the other of these two since (assuming that your flight uses the new airport) it is almost as easy to go between the airport and Pattaya as central Bangkok.  The other two are more challenging.  They are both considerably further.  They are in different directions from each other and from Pattaya.  You will almost certainly have to return to Bangkok to get to them.  So, you will need to be in and out of Bangkok multiple times.  The sequence of the visits won't make much difference.

You could visit all of those places in 14 days but you would spend quite a lot of your time travelling.  Consider dropping one so that you can appreciate the others more.  Maybe Phuket since you have two beach resorts in your list.  Bangkok, Chiang Mai (note spelling), and one beach resort will be very different.  Comparatively, Phuket and Pattaya will be similar.

Addition

What I call the new airport is Suvarnabhumi.  This is the one close to Pattaya.  Assuming that, go to Pattaya first on arrival.  This is quick and easy.  Return to Bangkok, make side trips to Chiang Mai and Phuket if desired.  These will be longer and harder.

There is the older airport Don Muang.  This is used for some short, budget flights.  It is not so convenient for Pattaya.  If you are coming from far away, you will probably not come here.  You might be able to get Phuket and Chiang Mai flights from there.  From Central Bangkok, the effort to get to either airport is comparable but they are in quite different directions.

Comment: Thanks, arrival and departure are both from BKK airport.

Comment: I thought on Arrival, while I'm still in the Airport, go to Phuket on a domestic flight, staying there for two days and staying in Phi Phi for another two days. After I'm back in Phucket I fly to Chiang Mai and spend two days there. After two days I fly to Bangkok and get a bug to Pattaya, after three days go from Pattaya to Ayutthaya. And spend the last few days in Bangkok. I though that this way I spend less time commuting between cities. How does it sound?

Comment: Check that the domestic flight is from the same airport.  They are not close to each other.  Also, if not bought as one trip, you need to consider the possibility of the in bound flight being delayed.  I would not do it that.  If you want to go directly to the beach then go to Pattaya first as it is an easy trip from the new airport.  I have not been for a few years but even a taxi is not much, especially if shared.  If you want cheap then take a bus.

Comment: Pattaya and Ayutthaya are quite different directions from Bangkok, you would probably go through Bangkok to get from one to the other.  I think that you will need to go in and out of Bangkok for each trip.  The only possible exception that I can see is Ayutthaya to Chiang Mai if you were taking a bus.  That is a slow tough trip.  Maybe sensible as part of a long, low budget backpacker trip but probably not for a short visit such as yours.